# Can I use one argument as the default argument in the same function?

Tags: python

I have a function in python with some arguments and I would like to use one of the arguments as a part of the default value for another one:

```
def this_function(a=1, b=a/2):
    return a, b
```

Is there any way of doing it without creating another if statement changing it to the a/2 at the beginning of the function? Or is it a bad practice?

Comment: You need to set its default value to `None` and use an `if` statement to reassign it to `a / 2` if it is `None`. This is because default arguments are evaluated once the function is defined, not when it is called.

Comment: Default values are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it's called. So it should be obvious that it can't depend on other arguments.